# Drawing shapes on html canvas in python/django

Tags: python, django, shapes

I am trying to draw shapes, line, triangles, rectangle on a web page using Django. How to accomplish this? Below is my code.

views.py

```
import tkinter
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def drawchart():
        root = tkinter.Tk() 
        canvas = root.Canvas(root, width=400, height=500)
        canvas.pack()
        blackline = canvas.create_line (0, 0, 200, 0)
        root.mainloop()
        return blackline
```

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <Head>
        <title>Line</title>
    </Head>
    <body>
       <h3>test</h3> 
       <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="500">
        {{drawchart()}}
       </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing server side and client side code. Unfortunately HTML5 canvas and tk canvas have nothing in common.

Comment: I want to draw and serve shapes in html canvas using django views

Comment: Please mark the answer accepted if it helped you.

Comment: @Abbas I switched to using SVG instead

Comment: @KapishM : I think it's good to post your solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 3):

`tkinter` is Python binding to OS native windowing libraries or GUI toolkit. What you wan to achieve cannot be done using it.

To play with `canvas` in HTML, you need to have HTML libraries for graphic programming. [WebGL](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/) is a javascript API which gives graphics capabilities to web pages. And [TheeJS](https://threejs.org/) is a javascript library which could be used for graphics programming on web pages.

WebGL being a javascript API, doesn't requires anything else to be included on your page and can be utilize via vanilla javascript calls. However, ThreeJS requires it's dependencies to be included on your page, just like jquery or jquery-ui and then you can leverage it as well.

I hope this answer would help you proceed in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use html canves in django templates or in views. Tk is only for desktop applications. Can't use tk on websites or in django views or in django templates.
Use html, css, js to drow in websites. Thinks this helps.